# How to put characters in a text file into an array in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, file

I have a project to be done , which is the maze game.

to set the field , I have used

```
const char random_field[15][20]={
"####################",
"#...#.....#.....#.?#",
"#.#.#.....#.#.....##",
"#.#.#####.#.#.######",
"#.#.#.......#.#.####",
"#.#.###.#######.####",
"#.#................#",
"#.####...#####.###.#",
"#.#....####..#.###.#",
"#.#.#........#.#...#",
"#.#.####..####.#.###",
"#.#....#.....#.#...#",
"#.######.#####.###.#",
"#..................#",
"####################"
};
```

and it works well !

but now I want to change the idea a little bit ..

I want to write this map into a text file and then declare a 2D array and fix the map in the txt file into the array..

I have wrote this but it doesn't work..

```
const char random_field[15][20] ;
FILE *filename;

filename=fopen("map1.txt","r");

for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; i < 20; j++)
{
    fscanf(filename, "%c", &random_field[i][j]);
}

}

for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; i < 20; j++)
{
    printf("%c",random_field[i][j]);
}

}
```

Any Ideas ? thank you

Comment: "but it doesn't work" doesn't say much. What are the signs that tell you it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some minor typos and you aren't handling the new lines properly.

```
filename=fopen("map1.txt","r");

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    //// You had i < 20 here.
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        fscanf(filename, "%c", &random_field[i][j]);
    }
    // Each row in the text file has a new line character on the end 
    // so scan for this.  
    fscanf(filename, "\n");
}

for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    //// You had i < 20 here.
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        printf("%c",random_field[i][j]);
    }
    // You need to add a new line in the print out after each row 
    // since it isn't mistakenly in random_field now. 
    printf("\n");
}
```

With your code, you were reading the new line character (or characters) into the first row of each random_field rather than skipping it.